# A question about the Guano Islands Act

Tags: united-states

Should I send a letter to a local State Department or the one in DC. I was also wondering if the government will still honor this law?

(U.S. Code Chapter 8 Title 48)

Answer (score 1):

The law has not been repealed. Assuming that the island satisfies the requirements for such a claim, probably the process starts with the Department of State (see [48 USC 1412](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/48/1412)), since you must

> furnish satisfactory evidence to the State Department that such
>   island, rock, or key was not, at the time of the discovery thereof, or
>   of the taking possession and occupation thereof by the claimants, in
>   the possession or occupation of any other government or of the
>   citizens of any other government, before the same shall be considered
>   as appertaining to the United States.

If the land is already claimed by the US, for example [Johnson Atoll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnston_Atoll), then the matter probably goes to the Department of the Interior who will probably say no because it has been deemed a wildlife refuge. It appears that all such islands of the US are reserved as a wildlife refuge or monument of some kind. There do not appear to be any actually unclaimed islands, which is important since the island has to be "not within the lawful jurisdiction of any other government".

Comment: "in the possession or occupation" sounds different from "within the lawful jurisdiction of any other government" is possession understood to mean claimed?

Comment: Which state department should I send it too. The local one or the Washington DC one?

Comment: Yes, you have to occupy it, and it can't be in the jurisdiction of another country, which I would interpret as meaning "is not claimed by anyone, such that we (would) recognize the claim". If you find an island at 10,-130 which is about 2,000 miles from anything, Kiribati probably would not have a *lawful* claim to the island. However, Minerva Reefs are about 290 miles from Tonga, the nearest country, so what counts as 'lawful  jurisdiction' it totally unclear (Tonga made their claim after Minerva was "formed").

Comment: Oops, turns out there's a piece of Tonga (Ata Island) within 200 miles of Minerva.

Comment: Why wont anyone answer my question : Which state department should I send it too. The local one or the Washington DC one?

Comment: I don't know of a "local State Department": if you deposit the affidavit with the D.C. office, I assume they would give you some reply.

Answer (score 0):

Exercise is discretionary. 48 USC s. 1411:

> [The island] may, at the discretion of the President, be considered as appertaining to the United States.

Comment: But, how do I let the government know I am claiming it?

Comment: and will the government let me know when they file the claim